# Stack Overflow login error with Google - IE 8

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I tried logging into Stack Overflow with my Google account in Internet Explorer 8, but,

I'm getting the following error:

[image]

And when I click on that *Error on page*,

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1;
Trident/4.0; SLCC2;
.NET CLR 2.0.50727;
.NET CLR 3.5.30729;
.NET CLR 3.0.30729;
Media Center PC 6.0;
.NET4.0C;

InfoPath.2; MS-RTC LM 8; Tablet PC 2.0)
Timestamp: Mon, 1 Apr 2013 10:26:38 UTC


Message: 'JSON' is undefined
Line: 109
Char: 405
Code: 0
URI: http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full-anon-c.js?v=4f2911519a40
```

What does this mean? What seems to be the issue?

I have been using the same Internet Explorer 8 for the past six months now, and it was fine until today.

Comment: I thought StackExchange is supporting only the current version and the previous version of a browser. That means, only IE10 and IE9 are supported.

Comment: I logged in day before yesterday, and it was fine!

Comment: I'm able to login with IE-7 :D

Comment: As an aside: why all the bold, and why format IE8 as `\`code\``? Please don't abuse the formatting. Also, Stack Overflow likes a space in its name.

Comment: ^ Edited accordingly.

Comment: IE8 Is not a supported browser (IE9+) - is it possible to use a different browser? This isn't a bug, though.

Comment: As for those edits: you just added a space in *one* occurrence of Stack Overflow, and now IE8 is emphasized rather than codified. Why? (I'm glad SE doesn't offer text colours...)

Comment: Voting to close as no longer reproducable, as IE 8 is no longer supported.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you're not running your IE8 [in Compatibility View](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/introducing-compatibility-view)?

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; ...
```

Above, it identifies itself as IE7.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and this is how I solved it:

1. Log in with Google account and then go to your profile and fill it with your information.
2. Now you are registered and have account in Stack Exchange.
3. Login with that Google account only, don't use the Stack Exchange login.