# How to handle potentially patronizing answers and comments (as a <2K user)

Tags: discussion, answers, suggested-edits, new-users

On EE.SE, a response to simple question an answer [was offered](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/64143/a-probably-very-easy-op-amp-analysis/64165#64165) that began with

> The answer is so simple !

I am operating on a premise that what is simple for some isn't for others, and that we are all here to learn something, and therefore lack of knowledge/experience is should not be considered a problem (this is different from lack of effort). The basic question is what to do about this (if anything) as a sub-1000 rep user.  I edited the answer to remove this, however, the answerer rejected the edit, and so the answer stands as is. Is the best solution:

- Do nothing?
- Flag? (Really?)
- Make a comment?  (isn't that "chatty"?)

Or am I blowing it out of proportion, and should just chill out. Full disclosure: I probably didn't help matters by with my suggested edit comment ("Removed the patronizing bits" or something like that), though one can do better next time :)

Comment: The title of the question is: _"A probably very easy Op-Amp Analysis"_... if kind of invited it... personally ignore it. I don't think it's particularly offensive.

Comment: Not "my" question in the sense that I posted in. Just sayin', but point taken.

Comment: Why not read it as an enthusiastic *"look with what little resources we can solve this problem"*?

Comment: @Arjan: Nice! I need more of that attitude in general. Where do I get me some of that?

Comment: [Don't ask me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174583/stack-overflow-question-formatting-guidelines-bold-italics#comment522622_174583), @angelatlarge ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suggesting an edit is the right thing to do, if you find it offensive. Though it may be best to be neutral in your edit comment and make the edit more substantial if possible.

The specific example you posted doesn't appear to be offensive enough to merit an edit, IMHO.

Answer (score 7):

Just ignore it.

It doesn't seem sufficiently disruptive to demand flagging/editing.  I might remove it when editing as a part of a more involved edit, but I don't think I'd edit a post just to remove that.

Answer (score 4):

Chill out a little IMHO, I wouldn't take this as patronising rather just a turn of phrase to indicate the solution that follows isn't going to be hideously complex. The comment could be considered a little unnecessary but I'd hate to see answers getting overly sterile with the odd half sentence getting edited out because they're "chatty".